# PHPStorm Class Hints with ::class

Tags: php, phpstorm

Whenever I start typing a name of a class in a constructor etc. I get the auto completion popup, where I can just press Enter to import the correct namespaced class that I wanted, but when I use the `::class` syntax (i.e. for `User::class` I'd start typing `Us`) I don't get any suggestions.

I guess this means that PHPStorm would need to suggest classes whenever typing as it doesn't know where I'm going to use `::class`...

Does anyone know a way around it? Or is this a feature that's in the works?

Thank you

Comment: What version of PHPStorm are you running? I'm on 9.0, and I definitely get auto-completion when I start to type `Us` for `User::class`.

Comment: @JustHelping PHPStorm 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to press `Ctrl+Space` twice after typing `Us`